# What does Buster say under the bleeps in the "Bringing up Buster" episode of Arrested Development?

Tags: dialogue, arrested-development

In the third episode of the first season of Arrested Development, titled "Bringing up Buster," there are two instances when Buster uses (what is assumed to be) obscene language to describe his mother, Lucille.

> **Buster:** [about Lucille]: It's like she gets off on being withholding. 
>   **Michael:** Whoa, Buster! 
>   **Gob:** Look who's ragging on the old lady! 
>   **Buster:** 'Because I'm an uptight... 
>   [long bleep] 
>   **Buster:** ...Buster... 
>   [long bleep] 
>   **Buster:** ...you old horny slut!' 
>   **Michael:** [stunned] Nobody's going to top that.

and

> **Buster:** And you might be [bleep] and it’s going to [bleep]. 
>   **Michael:** Well, let’s hope it doesn’t come to that.

What is Buster actually saying?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the Notes Section of the [Arrested Development Wiki](http://arresteddevelopment.wikia.com/wiki/Bringing_Up_Buster) for this episode, S1 Ep3, The Parents Television Council (PTC) had troubles with the profanity in the series, especially since in this episode Buster had two long strings of profanity.
It also noted that Tony Hale personally does not use profanity, so, if the script called for it like here, he would improvise.
The notes say that he was reciting the alphabet, and that it can be discerned by lip reading.
I rewatched the episode on DVD, with captioning, and this I cannot confirm. Captioning highlights the bleeps during the tirade, and the camera is mostly on the shocked expressions of Michael, Gob and Lindsay.
The second or two we actually see the lips move, I can't say we can see clearly that it is the alphabet.

Comment: So if it's not the alphabet, what DOES he say?

Answer (score 3):

The first string of profanity might be along the lines of

> and you'll be eating my shit that falls out (..?) inside of your mouth

but I haven't watched this scene with a higher resolution/quality yet.